# FindAll where to_days('createdAt') = to_days(now()) with sequelizejs

Tags: sequelize.js

Query data for the day.
Example: 
`select * from table where to_days(createdAt) = to_days(now());` .
How to use in sequelizejs.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `sequelize.where` and `sequelize.literal` ,

Here you go :

```
model.findAll({
    where : sequelize.where( sequelize.literal('to_days(createdAt)') , sequelize.literal('to_days(now())') )
})
```

For more : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#where)**